# Abrir documento de Ms Word en un editor de texto hecho en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ms-word

Teniendo un editor de texto hecho con Python y con la interfaz gráfica de Tkinter, puedo cargar el contenido de un documento de extensión ".txt". Pero, también, sin hacer nada especial, llego a cargar otro tipo de documentos como archivos XML, PDF ( aunque no se entiende mucho lo que carga pero carga algo ... :) ).

Este es el código:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox as MessageBox
import tkFileDialog as FileDialog
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

######## Python 3 ###########
#import tkinter as tk
#import tkinter.font as tkFont
#from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
#from tkinter import filedialog as FileDialog
#-> parece ya integrada en el import de * (tkinter.scrolledtext)

import os



class MiTkinter(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Ruta a guardar por si, más adelante, se guarda el archivo...
        self.ruta = ''

        self.prim_color = 'black'
        self.sec_color = 'white'
        self.ter_color = 'grey'

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg=self.prim_color, fg=self.sec_color)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg=self.prim_color, fg=self.sec_color)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Abrir', command=self.archivo_abrir)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Cerrar', command=self.archivo_cerrar)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.archivo_salir)

        self.parent_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=self.ter_color, padx=10, pady=10, width=300, height=345, relief="sunken")
        self.parent_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self._text1_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=10)

        frame_text1 = tk.Frame(self.parent_frame, width=300, height=345, relief="sunken")
        frame_text1.pack_propagate(False)
        frame_text1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.text1 = tk.Text(frame_text1,
                            wrap='word',
                            bd=0,
                            padx=6,
                            pady=4,
                            font=self._text1_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=24,
                            height=16,
                            bg=self.prim_color,
                            fg=self.sec_color,
                            insertbackground=self.sec_color,
                            highlightbackground=self.prim_color,
                            highlightcolor=self.sec_color,
                            yscrollcommand=self.on_textscroll
                            )

        self.text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.yscrollbar_gnral = tk.Scrollbar(self.parent_frame)
        self.yscrollbar_gnral.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.yscrollbar_gnral.config(command=self.on_scrollbar, bg=self.prim_color, bd=1)


    def archivo_abrir(self):
        '''Abrir archivo a analizar.'''

        print('Abrir archivo')

        #>> Ventana de Archivo :: Abrir
        self.ruta = FileDialog.askopenfilename(
                        title='Abrir un Archivo',
                        # Ruta por defecto para abrir archivo(s)
                        #   -> la raíz del aplicativo
                        initialdir='.',
                        #   -> la raíz del equipo
                        ####initialdir='/',
                        #   -> por defecto, si no se incluye el parámetro,
                        #       >> última ruta abierta
                        filetypes=(
                            ('Archivos de texto', '*.txt'),
                            ('Todos los archivos', '*.*')
                        )
                    )

        # Verificando que es una ruta válida para:
        #   -> abrir el archivo en modo de lectura ('r')
        #       >> ** NOTA **:
        #       se ha observado que, al abrirse el archivo, se agrega
        #       un nuevo salto de línea (\n) al final del contenido.
        #       Tener en cuenta esto al efectuar la acción de guardar.

        # [Cancelar] pulsado => Tupla vacía => ()
        if (self.ruta is () or self.ruta == ''):
            self.ruta = ''
            print('Abrir archivo >> acción CANCELADA')
        elif (self.ruta):
            fichero = open(self.ruta, 'r')
            fichero_contenido = fichero.read()
            # Asegurando que el TEXT queda vacío antes de cargar fichero_contenido
            self.text1.delete(1.0, 'end')

            # Pasando fichero_contenido al TEXT adecuado
            self.text1.insert(1.0, fichero_contenido)
            # Para colocar el cursor al principio del fichero_contenido tras cargarlo
            #   -> si no pone esta línea, el cursor aparecerá al final de fichero_contenido
            self.text1.mark_set('insert', '%d.%d' % (0.0, 1.0))

            fichero.close()

            print('Abrir archivo >> abierto correctamente   ¡OK!')


    def archivo_cerrar(self):
        '''Cerrar documento abierto.'''

        print('Cerrado documento')
        self.text1.delete(1.0, 'end')


    def archivo_salir(self):
        '''Saliendo del programa tras confirmación de la acción demandada.'''

        print('Saliendo del Programa   :(')
        # >> Ventana de Confirmación de [Si|No]
        #   -> según lo que pulse (Si|No >> True|False),
        #   se podrá hacer una cosa u otra
        ''''''
        msgb_conf = '¿Desea salir del programa?'
        confirm_siNo = MessageBox.askyesno('Confirmación ~ ¿?', msgb_conf)
        if (confirm_siNo):
            # self.quit()
            # o
            self.destroy()


    def on_scrollbar(self, *args):
        '''Scrolls both text widgets when the scrollbar is moved.'''
        self.text1.yview(*args)


    def on_textscroll(self, *args):
        '''Moves the scrollbar and scrolls text widgets when the mousewheel
        is moved on a text widget.'''
        self.yscrollbar_gnral.set(*args)
        self.on_scrollbar('moveto', args[0])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    root = MiTkinter()
    root.title('Probando ~ Carga de .DOCs')
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(360, 390, 400, 100))
    root.mainloop()
```

La cuestión es que, aparte de que cargue, correctamente, el contenido de archivo de texto con extensión ".txt", sería bueno que se pudieran cargar el contenido de archivos ".doc" o ".docx", es decir, archivos de Microsoft Word.

Ahora mismo, tal y como está el código, cuando abro un archivo de Ms Word, se imprime por la terminal el indicativo de que se ha cargado bien (`Abrir archivo >> abierto correctamente   ¡OK!`)
Pero lo único que se ve dentro del Text dónde, supuestamente, se ha cargado esto que se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, esa es la pregunta: ¿se pueden cargar archivos Word en este tipo de editores como el del código que paso?
Si fuese posible, o si alguien sabe o lo ha hecho antes, ¿me puede indicar cómo sería?

**NOTA EXTRA**: de primeras, me interesa saber cómo cargar documentos de Ms Word en este tipo de editor.
Pero si, luego, se puede hacer extensible la pregunta y saber cómo cargar el contenido de cualquier tipo de archivo en este tipo de editor, pues mejor que mejor ... :)

Comment: No es por desgracia tan fácil como cargar texto de una archivo de texto plano.  Además del texto va a contener otra información como el formato, imágenes, firmas digitales, etc. Son formatos complejos, con distintas versiones y estándares. docx es básicamente un zip con archivos XML, hay librerías que permiten trabajar con estos archivos como [docx2txt](https://pypi.org/project/docx2txt/) o [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) y extraer información que te podrían ser de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has practicado algo con alguno de ellos? ¿Cuál te parece más asequible? Según el README.md del Github de [python-docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt), éste es una adaptación del otro.

Comment: Bueno, tras mirar tus propuestas (referencias que ya había encontrado pero sin verlas muy al detalle), me puse a buscar algo más y, de entre todo lo encontrado, por ahora, me quedo con el código expuesto [aquí](http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/) de la mano de un tal @Etienne . Al cargar el contenido del documento de Word, solo se coge el propio texto perdiéndose todo el posible formato (tipos fuentes, tamaños, negritas, ...), las imágenes y tablas que tenga el archivo, ... Pero, por ahora, me quedo con él. Si que respeta, más o menos, los saltos de párrafo.

Comment: También, el llegado a probar el [doc2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt), con un resultado parecido al anterior, si bien la separación entre párrafos es algo más amplia, tendrá otra consideración añadida. También, tiene la opción de recuperar las imágenes. El que, por ahora, no he probado es en el que parece se basan tanto el código que enlazó como el **docx2txt**, con el que ya, parece se puede recuperar todo el contenido y, luego, tras manipularlo, se puede reconstruir el documento para terminar guardándolo con un aspecto sino el mismo, muy similar a como se cargó al inicio

Comment: **NOTA EXTRA**: probando la carga de archivos Word, he llegado a cargar de archivos bastante grandes, de varias páginas. Entonces, el movimiento de la barra de desplazamiento llega a un punto en que empieza a hacer como un bucle y no sigue avanzando. Parece que se produce un fallo en la función `on_textscroll()` o eso creo, pues, entonces, lo único que funciona es arrastrar el cursor de la propia barra de desplazamiento o, sino, colocar el cursor dentro del Text y desplazarlo con las flechas del teclado. Si alguien viese cómo corregir esto, sería de agradecer pues, por ahora, yo no lo veo.